# Cannot convert from UITableViewCell to specified type

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I am converting an app from objective-c to swift. I did not write the objective c code. One of the functions which code is as below...

```
func tableView (tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier: String = "Cell"

    var cell: ListCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier)!
```

And theres more code in the function but i don't think it is relevant. When I run the app, I get an error: `"nil found while unwrapping an optional"` at the line where I create the variable `cell`. The error is occurring because I am trying to convert a `UITableViewCell` to `ListCell` type. And the conversion is occurring and returning nil. I need to have this line in the code because it is there in the objective-c version of the app.

Is there any way I can get around this and convert a `UITableViewCell` to `ListCell` without the conversion failing and returning nil?

Here is the declaration of the `ListCell` class...

```
@interface ListCell : UITableViewCell {
    //code
}
```

I did not convert the `ListCell` class to swift, and instead use a bridging header. Also `ListCell` is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, so why is the conversion not working.

Comment: You need to check the storyboard and ensure that the class for the prototype cell with the reuseIdentifier `Cell` is set to `ListCell`. Also, your dequeue line looks odd; you are assigning an implicitly unwrapped optional to an optional. Normally you would see `var cell = dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as! ListCell` - but you still have to set the cell class for this to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` - The most common "modern" way is to have registered the reuse identifier and specified a custom class for your cell in your storyboard.  You can also use the `UITableView` method `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier` to do the same thing programatically.

```
tableview.registerClass(ListCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"Cell")
```

In this case you would say

```
var cell=tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as! ListCell
```

You can use a forced downcast because you know that the dequeue operation will return a cell of the appropriate type (and if not then you have a problem and throwing an exception is good so you can debug it).

The "old" way was not to register a class and deal with the fact that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` may return `nil` - In this case you need to allocate a new cell yourself;

```
var cell:Listcell

if let reuseCell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? ListCell {
    cell=reuseCell
} else {
    cell=ListCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
}
//  Now you can configure cell...
```

Comment: Can you please send the line of code for registering the class

Answer (score 0):

it should be

var cell: ListCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as! ListCell

Comment: try force unwrapping like this,var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as! ListCell

Comment: try debugging using break points then. that way u can know which one is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work fine.

```
func tableView (tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
 { 
let cellIdentifier: String = "Cell" 
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as! ListCell
```

Comment: One problem I forgot to mention. Right after that line I have a line that says: if cell == nil { do something}. So that is why I need cell to be an optional type.

Comment: Please remove that line it's of no use in this case

Comment: Also please check the class name associated with the cell on storyboard/xib

Comment: I created it by code so I need to add the class name by code in view did load. Can you please send the line of code in order to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this version:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell",
    forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListCell
```

The dequeue method version with index path never returns nil (creates new cells automatically, when needed).

The force cast `as!` either succeeds with a non-optional value, or crashes the app (in this case if the cell was not actually ListCell).